# How to api access relationship notes?

Tags: api, relationships

I tried this in the 4.7.25 demo but the same is valid for 4.6.33.

1. Using the web GUI I added a test description and test note to an existing relationship
2. With API browser I listed relationships with Relationship get to see the content of this relationship.
3. I only see the description listed not the note. Neither does Notes appear in the "Fields to return", nor can it be chosen as a filter Parameter.

Does this mean that Relationship Notes are not supported by the API? If so, how should report this? As a bug? A missing feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Note is stored separately, so you can get it via chaining:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'relationship_type_id' => 6,
  'api.Note.get' => array(
     'entity_table' => "civicrm_relationship",
     'entity_id' => "\$value.id",
  ),
));
```

To do that with the API explorer, use the Chain API Call button and enter the note parameters as JSON: `{'entity_table':'civicrm_relationship', 'entity_id':'$value.id'}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, updated my code accordingly that fixed it. Saved me much work.